# jQuery JSTree "uncheck node" perfomance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm getting a slow running script warning when I uncheck a large number of nodes in a jstree.

I'm using a loop to go through an array to get the id's and then uncheck the nodes. Is there an alternative way of doing this or making it faster? In my particular case my array length is 1600.

```
$.each(myArray, function(key, item){
  $("#myTree").jstree("uncheck_node", "!#"+item);
});
```

Comment: Well... as a first thing - you can prefetch `$("#myTree")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General recommendation when you need to do a lot of DOM manipulation - is to split it into few chunks using `setInterval/setTimeout`, so that browser will be able to handle user input and other events between your script executions.

For example (rough example):

```
var done = 0;
var chunks = 4;
var myInterval = setInterval(process_chunk, 1000);
var $myTree = $("#myTree");
var chunkLength = myArray.length / chunks;

process_chunk = function() {
  var arrayChunk = myArray.slice(done*chunkLength, (done + 1)*chunkLength) 
  $.each(arrayChunk,  function(key, item){
    $myTree.jstree("uncheck_node", "!#"+item);
  });
  done += 1;
  if (done === chunks) {
    myInterval.clearInterval();
  }
}
```

Comment: `array.slice(i,j)` - get the part of the array between `i, j` indexes, not including `j`. So I'm just getting chunks one by one.

Comment: Im not making it in the process_chunck function for some reason?